# How to rotate a video placed on a JFrame (VLCJ)?

Tags: java, swing, rotation, vlcj

I am wondering if it is possible to rotate 90 degrees a video played with VLCJ. Part of the code used for displaying the video is the following:

```java
        mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();     

        mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();

        frame.setResizable(false);  
        frame.setUndecorated(true);

        Canvas c = new Canvas();
        c.setBackground(Color.black);
        final JPanel p = new JPanel();

        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(p, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));

        frame.setLocation(650, 200);
        frame.setSize(1050, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);             

        mediaPlayer.playMedia(file);
        mediaPlayer.mute(false);
```

The code works nicely, the video can be watched without problems, but I would like to perform a rotation on it. I have looked up on the Internet but most of the posts are about rotation of images... so anyone can help me with that? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure you can, VLCJ simply "draws" onto the native peer of the `Canvas` which is used to show the video, you don't have any control over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the `MediaPlayerFactory`, make sure to specify the video filter and options you want as factory arguments, for example:

```
String[] args = {
    "--video-filter", 
    "rotate",
    "rotate-angle",
    "10"
};

mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory(args);
```

I don't think there's any way to set this dynamically while the video is playing.

The available filters come from:

```
$vlc --list
```

The available options come from:

```
$vlc -H
```

Alternatively, you could use a `DirectMediaPlayer` where you render the video yourself into a `Graphics2D` or OpenGL or whatever context and apply whatever rotation/transformation you want.

Comment: Nice, I finally used these options for MediaPlayerFactory: `"--video-filter=transform", "--transform-type=270"`. The video was rotated successfully.

Comment: Yes, the transform filter is a different way to rotate, but the rotate filter as described in my answer does work and is in fact necessary if you want to rotate at an arbitrary angle.

Comment: HI, Am trying to rotate the video content in the middle of playback - is there a way we can achieve that using "transform" or "rotate" ? @caprica

Comment: You can't change rotation during playback.

Comment: @caprica VLC player can do it dynamically when the media content is playing Tools -> Effects & Filters -> Video Effects -> Geometry -> Transform -> Change the drop down. Want to know if EmbeddedMediaPlayer can do it. Eg  `String[] MEDIA_PLAYER_FACTORY_ARGS = {
 "--video-filter=transform",
};
mediaPlayerComponent = new EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent() {
 protected String[] onGetMediaPlayerFactoryArgs() {
  return MEDIA_PLAYER_FACTORY_ARGS;
 }
};
String[] MEDIA_OPTIONS = {
 "--transform-type=180",
};
mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(MEDIA_MRL, MEDIA_OPTIONS);`

Comment: @caprica extending my previous comment, if the above method is not possible, recreate the player instance with the transformation the only choice through vlcj library?

Comment: There is simply no API provided by LibVLC to do what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @caprica, let me know if you have any suggestions sparks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is mistake:

```
String[] args = {
       "--video-filter", 
    "rotate",
    "rotate-angle",
    "10"
};
```

Should be

```
String[] args = {
    "--video-filter", 
    "rotate",
    "--rotate-angle",
    "10"
};
```

A half a day spent